# White speckle on chilli plant

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, chili

[image]
I've found these white speckles on my chilli plants and at first thought it could be Edema, but then I found these larger furry things on the top of the leaves and can't work out what they are, as they don't look like what images I can find of spider mites.
[image]

(They don't seem to move at all)

Any ideas on what it is and how to treat it?

Comment: The first picture is indeed edema. The second looks like aphids which have shed their exoskeletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact they don't move or fly suggests they are likely a type of spider mite, just white ones, though the photos are not clear enough to count the legs, nor can I see webbing anywhere. You can use an insecticidal soap spray or neem oil spray - heavier duty insecticides may not be suitable for use on food plants. Neem should work for longer than the soap spray. Try to avoid spraying open flowers, but do ensure you spray the underside and topside of the leaves and stems.